# Using a parent-class Object to create a subclass Object?

Tags: java, oop

I want to create an instance of a subclass that contains all the same fields as the parent Object, just with an extra field or two. My plan is this:

```
public subclass(parentClass parent, String extraField)
{
    super(parent.getField1(), parent.getField2());
    this.extraField = extraField;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this design?

Comment: extends parent class + super method in subclass constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine, it's just a copy-constructor-plus.

But ideally, define a copy-constructor on the parent class and use it instead:

```
public Subclass(ParentClass parent, String extraField) {
    super(parent); // <=== Using the copy constructor
    this.extraField = extraField;
}
```

*(Also, ideally, use Java standard naming conventions, at least when posting code for others to read... ;-) )*

Comment: I reckon one should make the copy constructor protected rather than public. Is that good?

Comment: @user3724404: That depends entirely on the class. For anything with instance state, a public copy-constructor or something that serves the same purpose is quite normal.